# jquery's slidetoggle: text gets smeared in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/rs4jhry8/.

HTML:

```
<div><button href="#" class="toggle">Button 1</button></div>
<div class="toggleContent"><p>This is a sample text.</p></div>
üüüüüüüüÜÜÜÜaaaa&Iuml;
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.toggleContent').hide();
    $('button.toggle').click(function () {
        $('.toggleContent').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

If you slide down a text with vowel mutations (capital letters only) like `Ü`, `Ï`, etc. using jQuery's `slideToggle()` these letters will be get smeared.

This only happens *when using Firefox but not in Safari*.

What can I do about it?
Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try wrapping your string of characters in a div with a little padding, say `padding: 1px 0`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not help. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could you specify the firefox version, I do think you should report it to the mozilla foundation as a bug

Comment: It's Firefox 36.0.1.